# Python writing twice but randomly?

Tags: python, csv

So I am currently working on a program that was handed down to me from a previous coworker and I am working through a strange bug. When reading data output from 2 separate serial sources byte by byte, python will write to the same cell in the .csv file as well as the console.

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime
import os

pressure_passed = False
arduino_passed = False
file_passed = False

BAUD_RATE = 115200

GARBAGE_CYCLES = 3 # how many cycles to ignore before logging data
garbage_cycle = 0

# Save data to log file
def LogData(startTime, pressureData, arduinoData, file):
    global garbage_cycle
    
    if garbage_cycle < GARBAGE_CYCLES:
        garbage_cycle += 1
    else:
        delta = datetime.now() - startTime
        ms = delta.total_seconds() * 1000
        dataString = "{:0.2f}, {}, {}\n".format(ms, pressureData, arduinoData)
        file.write(dataString)
        file.flush()
        print(dataString, end = "")



# Get the COM port for the Mark-10 Series 5
while not pressure_passed:
    try:
        pressure_com = input("Enter Mark-10 Series 5 COM Port #: ")
        pressure_ser = serial.Serial("COM" + str(pressure_com), BAUD_RATE)
        pressure_passed = True
    except:
        print("Invalid COM Port, please enter a valid port.\n-----")



# Get the COM port for the Arduino 
while not arduino_passed:
    try:
        arduino_com = input("Enter Ardunio COM Port #: ")
        arduino_ser = serial.Serial("COM" + str(arduino_com), BAUD_RATE)
        arduino_passed = True
    except:
        print("Invalid COM Port, please enter a valid port.\n-----")
    
    
    
# Get the name for the log file
while not file_passed:
    try:
        file_name = input("Enter log file name: ")
        
        # Add extension if not already given
        if "." not in file_name:
            file_name += ".csv"
            
        log_file = open(file_name, "a")
        
        # Add header row to log file
        if os.stat(log_file.name).st_size == 0:
            log_file.write("time (ms), pressure, rate (deg/ms)")
            
        file_passed = True
    except:
        print("Invalid file, or could not open the file specified.\n-----")
        
        
start = datetime.now()
        
# Variables to read serial input
pressure_data = ""
last_pressure = ""
arduino_data = ""
last_arduino = ""

# Main program loop
# Serial is read from byte by byte to better sync the two devices
while True:
    try:
        x_changed = False
        y_changed = False
        
        # Read from Mark-10 serial if available
        # x is a byte read from the serial line, converted to ascii
        if pressure_ser.in_waiting > 0:
            x = pressure_ser.read().decode('ascii')
            x_changed = True
                   
        # Read from Arduino serial if available
        # y is a byte read from the serial line, converted to ascii
        if arduino_ser.in_waiting > 0:
            y = arduino_ser.read().decode('ascii')
            y_changed = True
                    
        # If new data received, check if we should log it
        if x_changed:
            if x == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
                if last_pressure != pressure_data:
                    LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)    
                    last_pressure = pressure_data
                    pressure_data = ""
            elif x != '\r': # Otherwise, add the read character to the string
                pressure_data += x
                
        if y_changed:
            if y == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
                if last_arduino != arduino_data:
                    LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)
                    last_arduino = arduino_data
                    arduino_data = ""
                    
            elif y != '\r': # Otherwise, add the read character to the string
                arduino_data += y
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        if arduino_ser.isOpen():
            arduino_ser.close()
        if pressure_ser.isOpen():
            pressure_ser.close()
        log_file.close()
        break
```

Here is what the file is spitting out, IE the double printing to a single cell. [Sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8aXO.png)

Any advice is much appreciated, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when a new pressure is read in, but the value has not changed from last time, then it's not resetting the string that's accumulating all the characters and it doubles up. Then on the next pass, when the REAL pressure hasn't changed, it compares the doubled to the non-doubled and writes again, and vice-versa.

Try unindenting the line that resets the string to remove it from the `if` clause:

```
        # If new data received, check if we should log it
        if x_changed:
            if x == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
                if last_pressure != pressure_data:
                    LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)    
                    last_pressure = pressure_data
                pressure_data = ""
            elif x != '\r': # Otherwise, add the read character to the string
                pressure_data += x
```

Then the same thing for the arduino value block.

Your logs will probably be much shorter now.

Answer (score 0):

I like your username! My guess is that it is reading from the serial too quickly and going through the loop twice before the arduino has time to change the value of `in_waiting`.

At the top of your code add:

```
import time
```

And in the `LogData` function add:

```
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Give that a shot and let me know if it helps. 0.1s may be too long for your application but it is a good test to see if this is the issue. If it is, you can play around with the amount of time it sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample output provided, I think it's not writing twice but rather the following specific condition is met occasionally which calls two identical LogData() lines.

Only when Condition 1 **AND** Condition 2 are met - the data is written "twice". Note that the LogData() call is same in both conditions.

Condition 1:

```
# If new data received, check if we should log it
if x_changed:
    if x == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
        if last_pressure != pressure_data:
            LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)
```

Condition 2:

```
if y_changed:
    if y == '\n': # New line detected, log the accumulated data
        if last_arduino != arduino_data:
            LogData(start, last_pressure, last_arduino, log_file)
```